# sending data back from datatables to codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I am having a datatable displayed using jquery datatable from a codeigniter controller. What i wanna know is how do i send values from within the datatable back to a controller and use those values to retrieve new records from DB and then load them on again into the page.

My current code is

```
$(function(){
    $('#tableChart').dataTable( {
        // -------Function for formatting the table data elements-------
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {


                $.each(aData, function (i, elem){                       
                    $('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).html( '<b><font color="#40A913">'+aData[i]+'</font></b>' );
                }) 
                return nRow;
        },



            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bLengthChange": false, // Remove the show list drop down button
            "bInfo": false,         // Remove info part under the table
            "bFilter" : false,      // Remove search box
            "bDestroy": true,           // Remove table & recreate table

            "bServerSide": false,

            "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/print_db_table/get_print_db_table/<?php echo $table_name; ?>",

    });         
});
```

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="holderForTableChart">   
        <table width ="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="tableChart"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr id="tableHeadder" > 
                    <?php
                        foreach($table_header as $item):
                            $header = $item->name;
                            echo '<th>'.$header.'</th>' ;
                        endforeach;
                    ?>                                              
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <select id=""></select>
                <select id=""></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <select id=""></select>
                <select id=""></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <select id=""></select>
                <select id=""></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <select id=""></select>
                <select id=""></select>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                    <td colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody> 
        </table>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when i select a min max value in any one of the select boxes it must be sent to the controller from where i can send them to a model and collect them and reload them in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

humm... assuming this select box has id as #min_max_value
your javascript code will be something like in code down below.
This code will re-invoke ajax and will redraw table.
On the codeigniter controller u will be able to grab this min max value as $_POST['min_max_value']

i referred to this page on fnServerData  section for ur issue
http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks

```
var oTable = '';
$(function(){
    oTable = $('#tableChart').dataTable( {
        // -------Function for formatting the table data elements-------
        'fnRowCallback': function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                $.each(aData, function (i, elem){                       
                    $('td:eq('+i+')', nRow).html( '<b><font color='#40A913'>'+aData[i]+'</font></b>' );
                }) 
                return nRow;
        },
            'bAutoWidth': false,
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bLengthChange': false, // Remove the show list drop down button
            'bInfo': false,         // Remove info part under the table
            'bFilter' : false,      // Remove search box
            'bDestroy': true,       // Remove table & recreate table
            'bServerSide': false,
            'sAjaxSource': '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/print_db_table/get_print_db_table/<?php echo $table_name; ?>',

            'fnServerData': function (url, data, callback) {
                // Add new data 
                data.push({'name':'min_max_value', 'value':$('#min_max_value').val()});
                $.ajax({
                    'url': url,
                    'data': data,
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'success': callback,
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'cache': true
                });
            },
    });         

    $('#min_max_value').change(function(){
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
});
```

Comment: wow seems like this might work, ill give it a try and update the status here, thanks in advance for ur efforts

Comment: Hey, it seems that the data is not being sent back to the CI controller, even after the selection is made the thing just loads the same table

Comment: that's strange CI controller not receiving data, can u install firebug and place console.debug(data); right after this data.push({...}) code

Comment: hey i did that seems like the fnServerData function is not being called the sbsequent times. That is only when the page first loads its beeing called and the console logs the data from the next time when i change the drop down its not logging so the fnServerData is not being called. how shud i force call it

Comment: hey i finally wrapped it up inside a function and called the function each time when the dropdown thingy changes, thanks for the pointers @Aman

Comment: that's strange this jquery change event should have been triggered for that select box using this code $('#min_max_value').change(function(){}). It didn't trigger means something wrong with selexbox's id. So u wrapped up oTable.fnDraw() inside some other function ?

Answer (score 0):

And if anyone is using 'order' parameter of ajax return type from controller function in CodeIgniter must be array of arrays) (for eg: `echo json_encode($result)` in this $result must be an array of arrays) then this code can be very helpful.

```
    var manageTable;
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
    $('#putselectidhere').on('change', function (e) {

  //  $("#abc").css("display","block");

    manageTable = $('#puttableidhere').dataTable( {

        'order': [], 
        'bAutoWidth': false,
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bLengthChange': false, // Remove the show list drop down button
        'bInfo': false,         // Remove info part under the table
         'bFilter' : false,      // Remove search box
        'bDestroy': true,       // Remove table & recreate table
        'bServerSide': false,
        'sAjaxSource': base_url + 'controller/controllerfunction',

        'fnServerData': function (url, data, callback) {
            // Add new data 
            data.push({'name':'putselectidhere', 'value':$('#putselectidhere').val()});
            $.ajax({
                'url': url,
                'data': data,
                'type': 'POST',
                'success': callback,
                'dataType': 'json',
                'cache': true
            });
        },
});         







    });
```